# Integrate multiple mapped fields with spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  ID   |          mapCol1|          mapCol2|
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1234  |Map(1m -> 1,     |Map(1m -> 5,     |
|       |    3m -> 2,     |    3m -> 6,     |     
|       |    6m -> 3,     |    6m -> 7,     |
|       |    9m -> 4)     |    12m -> 8)    |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

if I would `explode()` this in spark it would start looking like this (there would be even more given that every key1 would have the full mapped field 2):

```
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
|  ID   |      mapCol1 key|      mapCol2 key| mapCol1_value | mapCol2_value |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | 1m              | null            | 1             | null          |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | 3m              | null            | 2             | null          |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | 6m              | null            | 3             | null          |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | 9m              | null            | 4             | null          |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | null            | 1m              | null          | 5             |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | null            | 3m              | null          | 6             |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | null            | 6m              | null          | 7             |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | null            | 6m              | null          | 8             |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| etc   | etc             | etc             | etc           | etc           |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
```

However, what I'm trying to achieve needs to look like:

```
+-------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
|  ID   |     Key 1&2     | mapCol1_value | mapCol2_value |
+-------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | 1m              | 1             | 5             |
+-------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | 3m              | 2             | 6             |
+-------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | 6m              | 3             | 7             |
+-------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | 9m              | 4             | null          |
+-------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234  | 12m             | null          | 8             |
+-------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
```

How could I achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using map_zip_with function.
An example written in python:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1234, {"1m": 1, "2m": 2, "6m": 3, "9m": 4}, {"1m": 5, "2m": 6, "6m": 7, "12m": 8})], ["id", "mapCol1", "mapCol2"])
df = df.withColumn("zipped", F.expr("map_zip_with(mapCol1, mapCol2, (k, v1, v2) -> array(v1, v2))"))
df = df.select("id", F.explode("zipped").alias("Key 1&2", "vals"))
df = df.select("id", "Key 1&2", F.col("vals")[0].alias("mapCol1_value"), F.col("vals")[1].alias("mapCol2_value"))
```

I have older pyspark version (3.0.1) without map_zip_with in API, so I used expr function to do that.

Same exmaple, but in scala:

```
df = df.withColumn("zipped", map_zip_with(col("mapCol1"), col("mapCol2"), (k, v1, v2) => array(v1, v2)))
df = df.select(col("id"), explode(col("zipped")))
df = df.select(col("id"), col("key").alias("Key 1&2"), element_at(col("value"), 1).alias("mapCol1_value"), element_at(col("value"), 2).alias("mapCol2_value"))
```